# Terraform Error: missing resource instance key

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.
Trying to create role and role binding in terraform.

I have terraform as such:

```
resource "kubernetes_cluster_role" "allow_port_forward" {
  count = (
    (var.env != "prod")
    && (var.env != "infra")
  ) ? 1 : 0
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      "CCE.com/IAM" : "true"
    }
    name = "allow-port-forward"
  }

  rule {
    api_groups = ["rbac.authorization.k8s.io"]
    resources  = ["pods", "pods/portforward"]
    verbs      = ["get", "list", "create"]
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "allow_port_forward" {
  count = (
    (var.env != "prod")
    && (var.env != "infra")
  ) ? 1 : 0
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      "CCE.com/IAM" : "true"
    }
    name = "allow-port-forward"
  }

  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "ClusterRole"
    name = kubernetes_cluster_role.allow_port_forward.metadata[0].name

  }
  subject {
    # developer group
    kind      = "Group"
    name      = "0f2762d3df0025dd3f71c00207c49c39"
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }
}
```

Terraform plan returns this. it complains about count, but unsure what to do with it.

```
Error: Missing resource instance key
│ 
│   on modules/rbac/cluster_role_binding/main.tf line 98, in resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "allow_port_forward":
│   98:     name = kubernetes_cluster_role.allow_port_forward.metadata[0].name
│ 
│ Because kubernetes_cluster_role.allow_port_forward has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│ 
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     kubernetes_cluster_role.allow_port_forward[count.index]
```

Comment: You need `name = kubernetes_cluster_role.allow_port_forward[0].metadata[0].name`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating the `kubernetes_cluster_role` resource with the count meta-argument:

```
  count = (
    (var.env != "prod")
    && (var.env != "infra")
  ) ? 1 : 0
```

that means if the condition is true, there will be exactly one instance of the `kubernetes_cluster_role`. Now, the `count` meta-argument adds indexes, so in order to reference any of the resources created with `count`, you need either to know the exact index or to use `count.index` object. Since the second resource, i.e., `kubernetes_cluster_role_binding`, is using the same `count` meta-argument logic, you can fix this issue with:

```
resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "allow_port_forward" {
  count = (
    (var.env != "prod")
    && (var.env != "infra")
  ) ? 1 : 0
.
.
.

  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "ClusterRole"
    name = kubernetes_cluster_role.allow_port_forward[count.index].metadata[0].name
  }
.
.
.
}
```

The [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count) has some pretty good examples.